# SQL - Append a count with a where has to query results

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have a Laravel booking app but am currently doing some manual reporting for a client.

I have a SQL query I run in SequelPro:

```
SELECT t.name
     , t.email
     , t.trial_ends_at
     ,
  FROM teams t 
 ORDER 
    BY t.trial_ends_at DESC
```

However, what I now wish to do is add another field to each row that shows the client count for that team.

The relationships for clients of a team is:

users can have many bookings,
bookings belong to a user,
bookings have a team_id field

What I wish to do is append the count of users where they have made at least 1 booking of that team id.

In Laravel's eloquent I would do:

```
return User::whereHas('bookings', function($q) {
    $q->where('team_id', THE ID)
})->count();
```

Comment: You may have a query, but this obviously isn't it!

Comment: @Strawberry - Are you having a particularly angry 2018?

Comment: @MatBailie So far, yes! ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry Im not following?

Comment: The query you provided would result in a syntax error. But you make no mention of a syntax error, therefore the query you've provided and the actual query you're using are different. Anyway, it looks like TB's got it covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join to a subquery which finds the counts:

```
SELECT 
    t.name,
    t.email,
    t.trial_ends_at,
    COALESCE(b.cnt, 0) AS client_cnt
FROM teams t
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT team_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM bookings
    GROUP BY team_id
) b
    ON t.id = b.team_id   -- this assumes that id joins to team_id
ORDER BY
    t.trial_ends_at DESC;
```

You had the following requirement:

> What I wish to do is append the count of users where they have made at least 1 booking of that team id.

It seems to me that a user would only appear in a record in the `bookings` table if there was a reservation associated with that record.  In other words, I don't think we need to do any extra check for this requirement, since if a user does appear, then by default he already appeared once.

Comment: The presence of a user in a table indicates that that user is present in the table?  OMG, that's amazing! ;)

Comment: @MatBailie LOL...the requirement struck me as being off.  I was actually prepared to have to rewrite my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your first query produce `$teams` then you could do something like-

```
foreach($teams as $team){
    $userCount = User::whereHas('bookings', function($q) use($team){
        $q->where('team_id', $team->id);
    })->count();
    if($userCount>0){
      $team->userCount = $userCount;
   }
}
```

This will append `userCount` if you have more then single `booking` in the `$teams` collections, otherwise not.